# Way to get around subdomain vs subfolder in terms of SEO?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo, subdomain

I have a main domain, www.example.com, that has ranking and 'trust' in Google. I'm creating a blog, but, for various reasons, I HAVE to host it on a subdomain, sub.example.com.

I know that when a subdomain is created, Google treats it as a new site and will eventually see it as part of the main domain (after a very long while). What I'm looking for here is a way around this or a way to expedite this process. Is it possible?

Possible solutions:

1. Using modrewrite to rewrite sub.example.com to www.example.com/sub. I'm not too familiar with rewriting so I'm not sure if it works like this. If it does, would this be a solution to this issue?
2. Creating a subfolder on www.example.com like www.example.com/sub, and, in that subfolder, include a redirect to sub.example.com. That way when Google crawls www.example.com/sub it will find the link to sub.example.com. Will it then see the subdomain as part of the real domain?

Are these viable solutions? Is there anything else that could be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Do you think you could add more detail as to why they won't work. I'm just trying to understand. And there is no way around hosting it on a subdomain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite won't let you convert the subdomain to a folder, but mod_proxy will.

You'll want something like this in your apache config file in the virtual host section for www.example.com:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /sub http://sub.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse /sub http://sub.example.com/
```

Then your blog is running in both places.  You'd probably want to put canonical tags on it so that Googlebot knows which is the preferred one.

Comment: Thanks. This is awesome. Is there an IIS equivalent?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

[Google treats subdomains and subdirectories the same](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/subdomains-and-subdirectories/). They do not see subdomains as new websites.